# When trying to upgrade to 2.3.2 getting a php version error

Tags: php, upgrade, magento2.3.2

When I access the website, I get:

> Magento supports PHP 7.1.3 or later. Please read Magento System
>   Requirements.

I have **PHP 7.2.19** on my stack

Where do I look for the problem?

https://siccaro.eu/

Comment: what commands are you using for changing php version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Use below commands for changing PHP versions**

> From PHP 7.1 => PHP 7.2

```
sudo a2dismod php7.1
sudo a2enmod php7.2
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

**check which PHP version you're using with this command**

```
php -v
```

Comment: I purged the old version and that fixed the error, but your solution also works fine, thanks!